# Looping through each row of 2D array with ForEach-Object

Tags: powershell, foreach, rows, multidimensional-array

I tried typing something like:

```
$test = ("c2","d8","e9"),(4,1,9)
(0..2) | % { "$test[0][$_] $test[1][$_]" }
```

And I should expect it to output:

```
c2 4
d8 1
e9 9
```

But I got this instead:

```
System.Object[] System.Object[][0][0] System.Object[] System.Object[][1][0]
System.Object[] System.Object[][0][1] System.Object[] System.Object[][1][1]
System.Object[] System.Object[][0][2] System.Object[] System.Object[][1][2]
```

What is the correct way to get the desired output?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use variables directly in a string, but when you need to expand something more complex like a property, item in an array or another expression, then you need to use subexpressions `$()`

```
$test = ("c2","d8","e9"),(4,1,9)
(0..2) | % { "$($test[0][$_]) $($test[1][$_])" }
c2 4
d8 1
e9 9
```

Answer (score 2):

Or you could use string concatentation:

```
$test = ("c2","d8","e9"),(4,1,9)
(0..2) | % {$test[0][$_] + " " + $test[1][$_]}
```

Outputs:

```
c2 4
d8 1
e9 9
```

Comment: +1 Such an old-school solution :) Love the expanding of variables and subexpressions in powershell. A great feature.

Answer (score 1):

You need to put those in sub-expressions. The reason why is that when it extrapolates variables within double quotes it starts at the dollar sign, and stops extrapolating at the end of a valid variable name. [0] is not part of the variable name, so wrap that in $() and it works fine:

```
$test = ("c2","d8","e9"),(4,1,9)
(0..2) | % { "$($test[0][$_]) $($test[1][$_])" }
```